# MySql Connection string on GoDaddy (remote server)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-connection, connection-string

I need to connect to a database on godaddy and insert some values. All the code is in place and it works on localhost. However I do not know how to connect to the online database. I chose the remote hosting option while creating the database on their web interface.

It does not work with localhost as apparently they are not hosted on the same server.

Specifically what I need to know is what I need to write into this.

```
$con = mysql_connect("WHATINEEDTOWRITE","username","password");
//note that mysql_connect is just given as an example to help clarify the situation.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ask your webhost, not us.  The answer is going to be specific to you, and won't help anyone else. P.S. try `localhost`.  P.P.S. `mysql_connect` is deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GoDaddy runs their database servers off a remote host.

Thus, your $con statement will look similar to the following:

`$con = mysql_connect("USERNAME.db.123456789.hostedresource.com", "DATABASE_USERNAME", "DATABASE_PASSWORD");`

You would then select the database in a following statement.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick, I looked at the header on the phpMyAdmin.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped

Answer (score 4):

Simple enough.

```
$con = mysql_connect("WHATINEEDTOWRITE","databasename","password");
```

"WHATINEEDTOWRITE" = "localhost" most of the time, meaning MySQL is on the same server the script is on. EDIT: It appears GoDaddy uses a remote host so do that instead of localhost :)

"databasename" = No no no, this is for your username not a database name!

"password" = Your password to go with username.

See this for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable remote connections to your GoDaddy MySQL Database: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases

That link is the official GoDaddy help article to instruct you on doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt it just be "localhost"? That is what it usually is.

Comment: It all depends on his webhost.

Comment: It is not localhost in the case of GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $con = mysql_connect("example.com","username","password") or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db("database",$con) or die (mysql_error());
```

example.com = ip / or dns-name of your provider / host

Comment: I tried the ip but it didn't work. also dns name didn't work either.